# Label is appearing two times for some areas. How i can solve the problem, label should be shown one time for one area

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling

I am working with ArcGIS. In some areas of the map labels are shown twice or three times for the same name and the same area. I want to have one single label for each area.

Comment: Have you checked if duplicated labels are not caused by topology issues, e.g. overlapping polygons (same polygons on top of each other).

Comment: Also, have you checked that you don't have the same layer added in your Table of Contents more than once?  It happens...

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Maplex Label Engine (Customize --> Arcmap options --> Data View).

Then you can go to the Labels tab on your layer with labels, click Placement Properties. From there you can manage a number of different things, I can really recommend clicking around for a bit and see what you can do.

What you are looking for is in the Label density tab.

[image]

You can even decide how far away two labels has to be in order to be considered as duplicates.

Comment: Usually you can set-up it for each feature layer individual. See also the point **Duplicate labels**  at [Prioritizing and positioning labels](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Prioritizing_and_positioning_labels)

Comment: in addition you can detect duplicate and fix labelling directly in table to force just one label (exemple you create a label just for bigest entitie ...)